# How do I get more regular stream position updates?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to show custom playback controls in my iOS sender app. Things work well enough except for showing the current stream position. I have a listener for the remote media client and I listen for media status updates so I can get the media info stream position. I then update my player view state to show latest movie playback elapsed time.

However, I get updates only every 10 seconds for media status updates. I really need to have much more regular updates than this, AT LEAST every second. Is there a way to get more regular updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use [GCKRemoteMediaClient#approximateStreamPosition](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_remote_media_client.html#a96898ab2b4a8c25a35dbf202efe6d9c0); run a timer and every second get the current position using the above and update your UI; this is a lightweight call and doesn't do a full trip to the receiver; internally it maintains and handles the current position.

Comment: Thank you Ali. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A slight issue with the timer approach is the stream total duration does not update up until you get the first 10 sec update, did you work out a way to get past that or are you not showing the total asset duration on a progress bar?